# How do I say neither off the off the table nor on the table.

Tags: expressions

I wanted to tell someone that this thing they are asking me is something I'm not actively pursuing but at the same time I did not rule it out completely. It's just that other things have taken priority at the moment. -- Thanks.

Comment: That table is off in another dimension at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idiom I would use is:

> It's **on my to-do list**.

This phrase implies that you have considered and prioritized the task but are not actively pursuing it.

Alternatively, another common idiom would be:

> I've placed it **on the back burner**.

This phrase also implies that you've put thought into the task but have since de-prioritized it for some reason.

Both of these phrases are informal. If you could offer a little more context to your question, I could provide a more appropriate answer.

Comment: I wanted to respond to the real estate agent about me looking for a place.

Comment: If you were trying to tell your real estate agent that you are still interested in finding a place, but that higher-priority things have come up, then I believe saying **"My house search has been put _on the back burner_"** is an appropriate response. If you disagree, please let me know, and I'll try to update my answer accordingly